# How to add custom controls on google map?

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-react

I am using google-maps-react library and i want to add cutom controls on google map like buttons, input elements etc. plaese see image i want like this.[image: i want to add custom control like this]

Answer (score -4):

google-map-react is a component written over a small set of the Google Maps API. It allows you to render any React component on the Google Map. It is fully isomorphic and can render on a server. Additionally, it can render map components in the browser even if the Google Maps API is not loaded. It uses an internal, tweakable hover algorithm - every object on the map can be hovered.

In the simple case you just need to add lat and lng props to any child of GoogleMapReact component.

```
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';
 
const AnyReactComponent = ({ text }) => <div>{text}</div>;
 
class SimpleMap extends Component {
  static defaultProps = {
    center: {
      lat: 59.95,
      lng: 30.33
    },
    zoom: 11
  };
 
  render() {
    return (
      // Important! Always set the container height explicitly
      <div style={{ height: '100vh', width: '100%' }}>
        <GoogleMapReact
          bootstrapURLKeys={{ key: /* YOUR KEY HERE */ }}
          defaultCenter={this.props.center}
          defaultZoom={this.props.zoom}
        >
          <AnyReactComponent
            lat={59.955413}
            lng={30.337844}
            text="My Marker"
          />
        </GoogleMapReact>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
 
export default SimpleMap;
```

Comment: but if we dragging map componet would be also drag with map. i need component that should be fix position. and the component position should not be depend on map lat long coordinates.